# Tail Loss Calculations

Tags: probability

> Two corporations each have a 4% chance of going bankrupt and the event
>   that one of the two companies will go bankrupt is independent of the
>   event that the other company will go bankrupt.
>
> We assume that each company has outstanding bonds. However, risks due
>   to changes in interest rates as well as the positive return due
>   tointerest are being ignored. A bond from any of the two companies
>   will return 0 if the corporation does not go bankrupt and 1 if it
>   does go bankrupt.
>
> Suppose an investor buys 1000 worth of bonds of the first
>   corporation, which is then called portfolio P1, and similarly, an
>   investor buys $1000 worth of bonds of the second corporation, which is
>   then called portfolio P2.

Calculate the tail loss for the portfolios P1, P1 and P1 + P2. Assume VaR critical level =5%

I solved the tail loss using:

Tail loss (P1) = Tail loss (P2) = 1000 x 0.04 = 40

Tail loss (P1 + P2) = 1000 x 0.0768 + 2000 x 0.0016 = 76.8 + 3.2=80

Should I divide the tail losses by their respective probabilities?

TL(P1) = TL(P2) = 1000x0.04/0.04 = 1000

TL(P1+P2) = (1000x0.0768 + 2000x0.0016)/(0.0768 + 0.0016) = 1020